# How can I solve this "Class Not Found" Exception in Spring?

Tags: spring

I have an error in my Spring program: "Class Not Found Exception." How can I solve it?

```
package com.app.sathya.test;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;


import com.app.sathya.bean.EmpService;
import com.app.sathya.config.AppConfig;

public class Test {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

              AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ac=
                     new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
                      
              EmpService E=ac.getBean("empService",EmpService.class);
              System.out.println(E);
              
              ac.close();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because EmpService is not defined.like @service or @component or it's not in components scope.

Answer (score 0):

So basically here you need to understand what's the difference between Java bean vs Spring bean.

Spring bean is an object that is instantiated, configured and managed by a Spring Framework container. So in order to mark any class as Spring bean you can annotate it with certain annotation like `@service, @component or @repository`, this will let spring to recognise that it needs to manage life cycle of that object.

Try annotating `EmpService` class with `@service` annotation, that should resolve the problem.